# Find the number of polynomial functions satisfying a given condition.

Tags: analysis, polynomials

How many  polynomial functions $f$ of degree $\geq 1$ are there, satisfying $f(x^2)=(f(x))^2 =f(f(x))$, for all real $x$?
I have found the function $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies the condition. I have no idea how to find it generally.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the degree of $f$ is $d$, then the degree of $f(x^2)$ is $2d$, that of $(f(x))^2$ is also $2d$, but that of $f(f(x))$ is $d^2$. We conclude $d=2$ (or $d=0$, but that's excluded).
So $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a\ne0$. Then $$f(x^2)=ax^4+bx^2+c$$ and 
$$f(x)^2=a^2x^4+2abx^3+\ldots$$
so that $a^2=a$, hence $a=1$, and $2ab=0$, so $b=0$. So now we can refine to
$$ f(x^2)=ax^4+c$$
and $$ f(x)^2=a^2x^4+2acx^2+c^2$$
and conclude $c=0$. It follows that $f(x)=x^2$ is the only possibility, and on verifies immediately that it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Suppose $f(x)$ has degree $n$, so that $f(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots$, where $a_n \neq 0$, and here and henceforth $\cdots$ denotes a sum of lower-order monomials than the one that appears before it. Computing the leading terms gives

\begin{align} f(x^2) = (a_n (x^2)^n + \cdots) &= a_n x^{2n} + \cdots \\ f(x)^2 = (a_n x^n + \cdots)^2 &= a_n^2 x^{2n} + \cdots \\ f(f(x)) = a_n(a_n x^n + \cdots)^n + \cdots &= a_n^{n + 1} x^{n^2} + \cdots \end{align}

> **Additional hint** Comparing degrees gives $n = 2$, and then comparing leading coefficients gives $a_n = 1$, so $f(x)$ must have the form $f(x) = x^2 + b x + c$ for some $b, c$. For which $b, c$ does it satisfy the conditions?